# shortest path between two railway stations when the edge weight is given

Tags: javascript, optimization

i have to find the shortest distance between the railway stations-

given is the nodes that represent the railway station and edges are considered as the distance. i have to calculate the minimum distance. there is some error in the logic i am using.

here is code that i tried. but i am not getting the shortest path between two points.
***to implement it*** : console: var e=new calc_route("1","3",steps) the solution should give me the minimum distance between 1 and 3 ..... for example there may be a path from 1 to 2 which has wgt 5 and 2 to 3 which has wgt 4 total is 9. and there may be a direct path between 1 to 3 with wgt 10. then the frst path should be selected

```
steps=[
    {from:1, to:8},
    {from:1, to:2},
    {from:2, to:7},
    {from:7, to:9},
    {from:8, to:9}
];

function calc_route(start, end, data)
{           
    console.log(start+", "+end);
    console.log(data);              
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
    {

        if(data[i].to == end && data[i].from == start)
        {
            console.log("Return");                  
            console.log(data[i]);
            return data[i];
        }
        else
        {
            if(data[i].from == start)
            {                       
                calcfor =   data.splice(i, 1);                                      
                calc_route(calcfor[0].topoint, end, data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not a homework. i have been trying to solve it myself.......... its an example of djkshrtas algorithm

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of the question you asked earlier today, and from the looks of your account history, have now deleted. This is ***not*** the desired behaviour from Stack Overflow users.

Comment: if you must have read the comments over there ... teh question wasnt clear to anybody. i tried to the coding myself. but when that didnt happen i reframed my problem in a better way

Comment: @Sree - You are missing prerequisite knowledge.  I recommend studying Dijkstra's SSSP Algorithm by itself first - work through it with pen and paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your should take a look at Dijkstra's algorithm. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Find an implementation of it in javascript, and reuse the already tested code.

Comment: i coudnt find any tested code in javascript @Phillip Nordwall

Comment: @Sree, try to read the code other people implemented in other languages and understand it, then, try to use the same ideas to write javascript code. If you have any questions about the original versions, i.e. what certain parts of the code does, feel free to ask it on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that what you need to implement is the A* algorithm...
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm)
A quick google will give you lots of already implemented results.